# Bizarre Safari behavior, shall I report it as a bug to Apple?

Tags: html, safari, ascii

I am looking at a webpage that shows different characters (all within 7-bit ascii) different from the html source. The problem seems to be specific to Safari (9.0.2, on MacOS 10.11.2), Chrome works fine. The following screenshot shows both the rendered text and the page source: see how the 
source "word-final" is rendered as "word-fioal". Similar errors abound. [Text source (available at http://seas3.elte.hu/phono/notes/nodiphthong.html, nothing special that I could see) and the way it shows up in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oin5J.png)

Comment: Please add the images and code into the body of your question and do a bit of formatting :)

Comment: I'm happy to, but I don't understand the request: the image is there, clickable, I'm not sure how to bring it closer to the body. The link is also there, but I'm reposting it here: [problem page](http://seas3.elte.hu/phono/notes/nodiphtong.html)